# 3D vehicle visualisation in MATLAB/Simulink

Tags: matlab, visualization, simulink

I am new to the MATLABS platform and am trying to understand how to display the 3D visualisation with graphs shown at 11:40 and at 18:10 in the video below, I downloaded and ran the example code that he provided but only the two spectrograms are operning.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

https://uk.mathworks.com/videos/radar-system-modeling-and-simulation-for-automotive-advanced-driver-assistance-systems-107121.html?elqsid=1551737420797&potential_use=Student

Comment: Please include the relevant code here, rather than linking to something external.

Comment: Youtube link as Mathworks page requires login:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cZ-NMsDKZ8&t=732s

Comment: That's part of the issue, its an example code that runs fine but the display I am trying to get wont show.

Comment: The code you downloaded and ran should be included in your question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the voice over at about 11:32, they have run the first simulation model, which is set up to write data to the MATLAB Workspace, and then to generate the virtual reality simulation they are running a second model.

From the video, at about 11:36, the second model appears to be called `VR_Simulation`.  This second model almost certainly requires the [Simulink 3D Animation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/sl3d/index.html) tools.

Comment: Thank you, I had completely missed that, and thanks for the link.